# remove this clicked list element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would really appreciate your help here. I want list item that is created with the "#save" button to be removed on click. The commented methods don't work. If i put 'h1' or something else it works no problem. Also the "#delBtn" button removes all list items no problem. But i cant;t make it work when i click on a list item to be removed. Thanks for your time in advance.

```
function Contact(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  let a_contacts = [];

    $("#delBtn").click(function(){
      $("li").remove();
    });

    $("#save").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault()

      var inputtedFirstName = $("input#new-first-name").val();
      var inputtedLastName = $("input#new-last-name").val();
      var newContact = new Contact(inputtedFirstName, inputtedLastName);
      $("ul#contacts").append("<li class='contact'>" +'First Name: '+ newContact.firstName + ' Last Name: '+ newContact.lastName + "</li>");

      a_contacts.push(newContact);

      $("input#new-first-name").val("");
      $("input#new-last-name").val("");
    });


        //---------------------------------------------------------------



      // $("li").click(function() { 
      //   $(this).remove();
      //  });


      //   $('li').click(function(e){
      //     $(e.target).remove();
      // });


});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/myjava.js"></script>
    <title>Address book</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="haha" >Address book</h1>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Add a contact:</h2>

          <form id="new-contact"><!-- form -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="new-first-name">First name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-first-name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="new-last-name">Last name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-last-name">
            </div>

            <button id="delBtn" class="btn">Add</button>
            <button id="save"  class="btn">Save</button>
          </form><!-- form -->

          <h2>Contacts:</h2>
          <ul id="contacts">

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="show-contact">
            <h2></h2>

            <p>First name: <span class="first-name"></span></p>
            <p>Last name: <span class="last-name"></span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a delegated event listener.  I believe that since these elements are being created dynamically, the event listeners don't find them and attach when the page loads.  Try doing something like this:

```
`$(document).on('click', 'li', function () {
     $(this).remove();
 })`
```

What is happening is the document takes the event listener on page load and passes click effects to all li's after they are created.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This worked like a charm. Thank you a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because you bind your click event on li elements that are *already* in your page at load time, and *only* at load time. This event won't apply for dynamically created new items…
[Try this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658774/1720332).

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove element li created by after document ready. You need use function [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Or you can write as below

```
$(document).on('click','li', function(){
   var el = $(this);
   el.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code should remove `li` items when clicked in the ul with id contacts.

```
$('#contacts').on('click', 'li', function (event) {
      $(event.target).remove()
});
```